# How to reactive my health kit activation options on my app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, healthkit

I am new with cordova healthkit plugin. I was wondering, the first time I ran my app, I was shown the window with options to activate (example, height, weight, ...) : http://plugins.telerik.com/images/default-source/plugins/healthkit/ios-screenshot-3.png?sfvrsn=5

what to do to see that window again on my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

go to health app it is where different options are activated